# Understanding the output of of convhull

Tags: matlab

Can someone please explain me the values stored in `kk` for

```
A=[2 0 0; 
   0 2 0; 
   0 0 2;
   1 1 sqrt(2)];

kk= convhull(A);
```

values in `kk`:

```
1   2   4
1   3   2
1   4   3
2   3   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the documentation of [`convhull`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html)?

It clearly explains (for the 3D case):

> `K = convhull(X,Y,Z`) returns the 3-D convex hull of the points (X,Y,Z), where X, Y, and Z are column vectors.
>   K is a triangulation representing the boundary of the convex hull. K is of size mtri-by-3, where mtri is the number of triangular facets. That is, each row of K is a triangle defined in terms of the point indices.

In your example the convex hull of the the 4 points in `A` is defined by the four triangular facets

```
[1 2 4] --> [ (2,0,0), (0,2,0), (1,1,sqrt(2)) ] %// first triangle
[1 3 2] --> [ (2,0,0), (0,0,2), (0,2,0) ] %// second triangle
...
```

Comment: thanks
.............
1 2 4] --> [ (2,0,0), (0,2,0), (1,1,sqrt(2)) ] %// first triangle
[1 3 2] --> [ (2,0,0), (0,0,2), (0,2,0) ] %// second triangle
.............

is what I was unable to understand from the documentation

Comment: How to get the individual vertex from 3d convex hull.

From what I have understood, matlab's convex hull  i.e. convhull(X,Y,Z) output a triangular indices matrix.
What I want is xVertices,yVertices,zVertices that actually contribute to the convex hull.
Is there a method to do that or I should iterate through each triangular indices and then fetch the corresponding row of input matrix?

Comment: @RusheelJain I want to understand your question: suppose you have `A` with `n` points in 3D (`n`-by-3 size of `A`) you wish to know which points of the `n` are actually on the boundary of the convex hull and which are interior to the convex hull?

Comment: I was able to get answer for question that I asked in my previous comment

Comment: well actually yes I wanted to know exactly what you mentioned in your previous comment.
My only doubt was that since convexhull() was giving triangular indices so how can we do find the actual vertex indices

But it was pretty easy
I simply ran unique() to get the unique indices
now we have unique indices of each row that contributes to boundary points (convex hull) and hence we can get the values

But thanks for explaining the value of 'kk'

Comment: @RusheelJain no problem and well done on making the `unique` step to extract the boundary vertices.